# Visiting All Nodes and Adding Them to Path

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to visit all nodes, get back to start node(`Neamt`) and add visited nodes to `path` but problem is If I reach dead end, city deleted from the `path`.

[image]

Here is the 1 of the possible `path` that code produces:

`['Neamt', 'Iasi', 'Vaslui', 'Urziceni', 'Bucharest', 'Fagaras', 'Sibiu', 'Oradea', 'Zerind', 'Arad', 'Timisoara', 'Lugoj', 'Mehadia', 'Drobeta', 'Craiova', 'Pitesti', 'Rimnicu Vileea']`

As shown in above `path`, there are no `'Hirsova', 'Eforie', 'Giurgiu'`.
What really happen is while I debug on PyCharm: `'Hirsova', 'Eforie', 'Giurgiu'` are added to `path` but then they are deleted from `path`.

**I want to include those cities to `path` as reversed order.** Such as:

`['Neamt', 'Iasi', 'Vaslui', 'Urziceni', 'Hirsova', 'Eforie', 'Hirsova', 'Urziceni', 'Bucharest', 'Giurgiu', 'Bucharest', 'Pitesti', 'Rimnicu Vileea', 'Craiova', 'Drobeta', 'Mehadia', 'Lugoj', 'Timisoara', 'Arad', 'Zerind', 'Oradea', 'Sibiu', 'Fagaras', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt',]`

*Why they are deleted from `path` since there is no any opposite of `.append` method like `.delete`?*

```
def find_paths(node, cities, path, distance):
    # Add way point
    path.append(node)
    #print('path:', path)

# Fork paths for all possible cities not yet used
    for city in cities:
        if (city not in path) and (node in cities[city]):
            find_paths(city, dict(cities), list(path), distance)
#What has to be:
count = 0 # avoid adding end paths twice
    for city in cities[node].keys(): # only recurse on children not the whole list
        if city not in visited: 
            count += 1
            find_paths(city, cities, path, distance, visited)
    if count > 0 : # only add again if there were children
        path.append(node)
#////////////

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cities = {
    'Arad': {'Sibiu': 140, 'Timisoara': 118, 'Zerind': 75},
    'Hirsova': {'Eforie': 86, 'Urziceni': 98},
    'Bucharest': {'Fagaras': 211, 'Giurgiu': 90, 'Pitesti': 101, 'Urziceni': 85},
    'Craiova': {'Drobeta': 120, 'Pitesti': 138, 'Rimnicu Vileea': 146},
    'Drobeta': {'Craiova': 120, 'Mehadia': 75},
    'Eforie': {'Hirsova': 86},
    'Fagaras': {'Bucharest': 211, 'Sibiu': 99},
    'Giurgiu': {'Bucharest': 90},
    'Iasi': {'Neamt': 87, 'Vaslui': 92},
    'Lugoj': {'Mehadia': 70, 'Timisoara': 111},
    'Mehadia': {'Drobeta': 75, 'Lugoj': 70},
    'Neamt': {'Iasi': 87},
    'Oradea': {'Sibiu': 151, 'Zerind': 71},
    'Pitesti': {'Bucharest': 101, 'Craiova': 138, 'Rimnicu Vileea': 97},
    'Rimnicu Vileea': {'Craiova': 146, 'Pitesti': 97, 'Sibiu': 80},
    'Sibiu': {'Arad': 140, 'Fagaras': 99, 'Oradea': 151, 'Rimnicu Vileea': 80},
    'Timisoara': {'Arad': 118, 'Lugoj': 111},
    'Urziceni': {'Bucharest': 85, 'Hirsova': 98, 'Vaslui': 142},
    'Vaslui': {'Iasi': 92, 'Urziceni': 142},
    'Zerind': {'Arad': 75, 'Oradea': 71}
    }

    #print("Start: Neamt")
    find_paths('Neamt', cities, [], 0)
```

Comment: you can try to remove copying objects in statements `dict(cities)`, `list(path)` and leave them `cities`, `path`

Comment: you need use an algorithm from [theory of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov They show up but can't reach back to start node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to do depth-first search and add nodes before you enter recursion and after. This puts a name on the list as you start the path and then again on the way back as recursion unwinds. The process is:

1. Add City
2. Recurse on children (if child is unvisited)
3. Add city again (if it is not the end of a path)

You need to add the check for path ends so you don't add cities like Eforie twice in a row. If a city has no unvisited children, you don't add it again. To do this, just keep track of the count of recursions.

Something like:

```
def find_paths(node, cities, path, distance, visited = set()):

    visited.add(node) # keep track of visited nodes
    path.append(node)

    # Fork paths for all possible cities not yet used
    count = 0 # avoid adding end paths twice
    for city in cities[node].keys(): # only recurse on children not the whole list
        if city not in visited: 
            count += 1
            find_paths(city, cities, path, distance, visited)
    if count > 0 : # only add again if there were children
        path.append(node)

a = []
find_paths('Neamt', cities, a, 0)
print(a)
```

Results in

> ['Neamt', 'Iasi', 'Vaslui', 'Urziceni', 'Bucharest', 'Fagaras', 'Sibiu', 'Arad', 'Timisoara', 'Lugoj', 'Mehadia', 'Drobeta', 'Craiova', 'Pitesti', 'Rimnicu Vileea', 'Pitesti', 'Craiova', 'Drobeta', 'Mehadia', 'Lugoj', 'Timisoara', 'Zerind', 'Oradea', 'Zerind', 'Arad', 'Sibiu', 'Fagaras', 'Giurgiu', 'Bucharest', 'Hirsova', 'Eforie', 'Hirsova', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt']

Comment: Whenever `count` incremented by one, `find_paths` calling. How `if count > 0` become true?

Comment: @ilvthsgm Each iteration of `find_paths` will get its own version of `count`. So when we increment `count += 1` it is only in scope in the call of the function. After looking at all the children it will represent how many nodes we visited after this one before coming back.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is ever deleted, you're simply seeing different frames of `find_paths` with different values of `path`. `list(path)` makes copies so each function call receives its own list, and once a function call ends and you move back up the recursion stack you see an old value of `path` that didn't have a node appended to it.

Comment: Good point, thank you. Can you suggest any algorithm to check all nodes and get back to start node?(`Single source algorithm`)

Comment: It's not TSP @AlexHall - it's plain old depth-first search.